# Insert image sources in lots of divs (best way)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i made an rack in html & css:

```
<div id="achterkant">
  <div class="rack">
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rackRow">
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
      <div class="rackSlot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In all these rackSlots there needs to be an image i get from my API (just a link). I have these in an array. Is there a way to just insert the images in de first div with class rackslot, that has no image in it?
This is how I think I should do it:

```
   for (i = 0; i < 36; i++){
       $('first rack slot with no images').prepend('<img src="'myarrayofimages[i]'"/>');
   }
```

Comment: So you're asking for the selector to use with jQuery? Try `$('.rackSlot:not(:has(img))')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that your string concatenation is flawed - you're missing the `+` to join the values.

To achieve what you require you can use `:empty:first` to select the required `.rackSlot` element:

```
for (i = 0; i < 36; i++){
  $('.rackSlot:empty:first').prepend('<img src="' + myarrayofimages[i] + '"/>');
}
```

If you want to make it a little more precise you could explicitly check that it doesn't contain an `img` element:

```
for (i = 0; i < 36; i++){
  $('.rackSlot:not(:has(img)):first').prepend('<img src="' + myarrayofimages[i] + '"/>');
}
```